# what are the differences between "name" and "type" in roslaunch?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what are the differents between "name" and "type" in roslaunch for nodes?

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="fake_localize" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 10"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61983/what-are-the-differences-between-%22name%22-and-%22type%22-in-roslaunch?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Type is the file you want to launch in the package  whereas the name is a unique identifier for your node.

In your example it will launch static_transform_publisher in package tf with name of the node as fake_localize.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node

---

Originally posted by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) with karma: 358 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-05-02**:
tnx for your link. for complete the answre, for example in my launch file >> the "fake_localize"(NAME) node is uniqe arbitrary name, (you can see in rxgraph!) using the "static_transform_publisher" (TYPE) executable from the "tf" package.

**Comment by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on 2013-05-02**:
Yes that's right!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to find out what to initialize in the type is to go to your CMakeLists.txt. Find the line that says something like add_executable(blah_blah src/whatever.cpp) then blah_blah is the type. Another way is to cd to your /devel/lib/ folder, dig into your package and there you will see the executables(probably, in green).

---

Originally posted by [oogabooga](https://answers.ros.org/users/20648/oogabooga/) with karma: 51 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fenglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/92911/fenglong/) on 2022-04-14**:
Thanks for the answer. While using C++ the "type" in launch file should be the name of the target in CMakeLists.txt, but when using Python it should be the "XXX.py", is that correct?